# Setting image src dynamically in reactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm trying to set up an image src dynamically in reactJS, I'm using typescript and the code is as follows regarding the image.

This is just a segment of my code demonstrating the logic im trying to follow with updating the weather icon in my app.

Please, if you have other comments don't be shy to share them i'll be more than happy to accept any constructive criticism but mainly please help with the main issue I have here.

```
  const [Icon, setIcon] = useState("");
 useEffect(() => {
    switch (Icon.substr(0, 2)) {
      case "01":
        setIcon(sun);
        break;
      case "50":
        setIcon(fog);
        break;
      case "09":
        setIcon(drizzle);
        break;
      case "11":
        setIcon(storm);
        break;
      case "09" || "13" || "10":
        setIcon(rain);
        break;
      case "13":
        setIcon(snow);
        break;
      case "02" || "03" || "04":
        setIcon(clouds);
        break;
      default:
        setIcon(sun);
    }
  }, [Icon]);


return(<img src={Icon} />)
```

---FULL CODE ----

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import Clock from "react-live-clock";
import Loading from "../components/PageLoader";
import rain from "../images/rain.svg";
import drizzle from "../images/drizzle.svg";
import fog from "../images/fog.svg";
import clouds from "../images/cloud.svg";
import snow from "../images/snowflake.svg";
import storm from "../images/storm.svg";
import sun from "../images/sun.svg";

export default function Home() {
  let cityName: string;
  const [city, setCity] = useState("amman");
  const [Icon, setIcon] = useState("");
  const changeC = document.getElementById("C");

  const changeF = document.getElementById("F");
  const [triggerEffect, setTriggerEffect] = useState(0);
  const textChange = (event: any) => {
    cityName = event.target.value;
  };

  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(Object);

  const time = Date();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/app/weather?address=${city}`)
        .then((response) => {
          setWeatherData(response.data);
          setIcon(response.data.weather["0"].icon);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [triggerEffect]);
  const [celsius, setCelsius] = useState(true);
  const onSubmitText = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTriggerEffect(triggerEffect + 1);
    if (cityName) {
      setCity(cityName);
    }
  };
  function convertCels() {
    setCelsius(true);
    console.log(changeF + " " + changeC);
    if (changeC && changeF) {
      changeC.style.color = "#0000ff";
      changeF.style.color = "000000";
    }
  }
  function convertFeh() {
    setCelsius(false);
    console.log(changeF + " " + changeC);
    if (changeC && changeF) {
      changeC.style.color = "#000000";
      changeF.style.color = "0000ff";
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (Icon.substr(0, 2)) {
      case "01":
        setIcon(sun);
        break;
      case "50":
        setIcon(fog);
        break;
      case "09":
        setIcon(drizzle);
        break;
      case "11":
        setIcon(storm);
        break;
      case "09" || "13" || "10":
        setIcon(rain);
        break;
      case "13":
        setIcon(snow);
        break;
      case "02" || "03" || "04":
        setIcon(clouds);
        break;
      default:
        setIcon(sun);
    }
  }, [Icon]);
  return weatherData["name"] && Icon ? (
    <MainContainer>
      <Header />
      <SearchBoxDiv>
        <Button type="submit" onClick={onSubmitText}></Button>
        <SearchBox
          id="text"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Location"
          onChange={textChange}
        ></SearchBox>
      </SearchBoxDiv>
      <MainMidContainer>
        <SecMidContainer>
          <Vector src={Icon} />
        </SecMidContainer>
        <SecMidContainer>
          <CityName>{weatherData["name"]}</CityName>
          <Time>
            {time.toString().substr(0, 3) + " "}
            <Clock format={"HH:mm"} ticking={true} timezone={"Asia/Amman"} />
          </Time>
          <Condition>{weatherData.weather["0"].description}</Condition>
          <Temp id="temp">
            {celsius
              ? parseInt(weatherData.main["temp"]) - 270 + " C"
              : parseInt(
                  parseInt(weatherData.main["temp"]) * (9 / 5) - 459 + "",
                ) + " F"}
            {"   "}
            <SuperScriptC
              onClick={() => {
                convertCels();
              }}
            >
              C
            </SuperScriptC>
            {"   "}
            <SuperScriptF
              id="F"
              onClick={() => {
                convertFeh();
              }}
            >
              F
            </SuperScriptF>
          </Temp>
        </SecMidContainer>
      </MainMidContainer>
      <Footer />
    </MainContainer>
  ) : (
    <Loading />
  );
}
const MainContainer = styled.div`
  width: 1400px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const SearchBoxDiv = styled.form`
  width: 500px;
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
`;
const SearchBox = styled.input`
  width: 497px;
  height: 54px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
`;

const MainMidContainer = styled.div`
  width: 900px;
  heigh: 330px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: center;
`;

const SecMidContainer = styled.div`
  width: 40%;
  height: 330px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const Vector = styled.img`
  height: 330px;
  width: 330px;
`;
const CityName = styled.p`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 47px;
`;
const Time = styled.p`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 47px;
`;
const Condition = styled.p`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
`;

const Temp = styled.p`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 117px;
  margin-top: 15 %;
`;
const SuperScriptC = styled.sup`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 47px;
`;
const SuperScriptF = styled.sup`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 47px;
`;
const Button = styled.input`
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
`;
```

Comment: Please highlight the issue you are facing.

Comment: the issue is the icon doesnt change on my page when i enter a new location in the input field

Comment: In fetchData function  change yoyr setIcon to this ```setIcon(response.data.weather[0].icon)```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem: useEffect Dependencies

Your `useEffect` has `Icon` as a dependency but it is also setting `Icon`.  So every time that it changes the icon it will run again.  There is potential for an infinite loop with this setup.  Currently what's happening is that is always ends up on `sun` from the `default` case because whenever you set it to something else, it triggers a re-run with the new value.

#### Solution 1: Better Dependencies

We want to reset the `Icon` whenever the `weatherData` changes.  Rather than calling `setIcon(response.data.weather["0"].icon)` (delete that line), we use the icon from the data to trigger the effect.  The data is already stored in state as `weatherData`.

```
// you need to fix your initial value of weatherData, but I think this will work
const weatherIcon = weatherData?.weather?.[0]?.icon;

useEffect(() => {
    switch (weatherIcon.substr(0, 2)) {
      case "01":
        setIcon(sun);
        break;
      /* ... */
    }
  }, [weatherIcon]);
```

#### Solution 2: Pure Function

We are just choosing an icon based on a `string` value in the API response.  This does not need to be an effect.  We can define a function that finds the icon for a given `string`  and call that function ourselves at the appropriate time.  This function also saves you from having to write `break` a bunch of times because we are calling `return`.

```
const findIcon = (weatherIcon: string) => {
  switch (weatherIcon.substr(0, 2)) {
      case "01":
        return sun;
      case "50":
        return fog;
      /* ... */
      default:
        return sun;
    }
}
```

You would call this function in your `fetch` effect and delete the icon update effect.

```
.then((response) => {
  setWeatherData(response.data);
  setIcon(findIcon(response.data.weather["0"].icon));
});
```

There are some other issues with your code, but this should fix the icon situation.